# SSIS multiline string variables , in VS 2008

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I need to store a large query into a string variable.

When I paste the sql query into the Value property of the variable, I see only one line.
I am using VS 2008 , BIDS to design the package. 
I think this is a bug as stated [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/667242/ssis-variables-window-should-allow-line-breaks-crlf-in-a-variable-value),

what I am actualy intersted is a workaround to bypass this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a parameters table in a SQL database, then load long strings into variables using a simple SQL query.  This has the additional advantage that you can refactor the query code without opening SSIS.

It also allows multiple packages to easily share common query code.

Edit:  Of course, if you only want to do this once...

Manually edit the XML.  Put a placeholder value in the variable, then open the .dtsx in a text editor, locate the placeholder value, and replace it with the value you need.

Please back up your package prior to doing this.

Comment: thank you, yes that sounds really good, I will use it in the future, just that now I need something just to pass this SQL to the  OLE DB Source editor

Comment: I managed to sort it out by creating a stored procedure, and calling te from the OLE DB Source;  but that is awsome,  to edit the XML, I will remember that too, for when I need a fast change and not having VS at hand. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another work around - you can set the EvaluateAsExpression to True and put the SQL query in the Expression.  The Expression will have a `...` button which you can click to edit a multi-line value.

Comment: I tried this, I forgat to mention that when tring I got an error saying the string is too large , over 4000 characters. Ta

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation.  Sorry this is not helpful - glad to hear that the proc solution works.